# "Length cannot be less than zero." after database manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, iis

First of all, I'd like to apologize in advance for my lack of proficiency in the area of C#.

Although I have very little knowledge of the subject I was in a situation where I needed to create an exact copy of a website. The website is using .NET 4.0, runs on IIS 7 with MSSQL Server 2008. The new website is set up as a subdomain of the old one.

I did a full backup of the original database, created a new database and "restored" it with the orginal's backup. The only thing I changed was the .mdf and .ldf files.

I then copied and pasted the actual files to the new folder and changed the config files with the new database.

Everything works perfectly until you add/delete news to/from the database. At that point, the front page of the website renders the following message:

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Length cannot be less than zero.

Parameter name: length

Stack trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
 Parameter name: length]
 System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean               fAlwaysCopy) +10082776
 Tang.Core.Utility.HtmlHelper.CutText(String rawText, Int32 length) +242
  Tang.Website.UC.ArticleItems.GetLegacyDataTable(Int32 collectionId, Int32 maxRecord)   +2172
 Tang.Website.UC.ArticleItems.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +150
  System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t,   EventArgs e) +25
  System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Another error is when a user is logged in (again "length cannot be zero"):

```
    <%-- <p class="news_date"><%# Eval("collectionitemdatetime", "{0:d}") %></p>--%>
            <p class="news_cont">
                **<%# Tang.Core.Utility.HtmlHelper.CutText( Eval("collectionitemtext").ToString(), 450) %>** --> THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS, OBVIOUSLY STRING IS EMPTY?</p>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I am totally lost as nothing "major" has been edited from the original. I must be doing something wrong with the database.

EDIT: The thing is, as soon as I change the datbase from the webconfig file [to the original database], everything works, I can add/remove/edit items and they are shown on the home page. So it's gotta be something between the website & the database and not code-related

**EDIT 2, Found a solution:** I deleted the database, created a new one and instead of doing a "restore", I did "Export" from the original one. I had to set the primary keys manually and change some of them to (Is Identify) - Yes because I was getting the same error. Not the most elegant solution but at least everything seems to be working now.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: It'd be good to see the source to `HtmlHelper.CutText`.

Comment: Have you confirmed the rows are being added to the database?

Comment: @Phil - What is the value of `Eval("collectionitemtext").ToString()`?  You should also post the code to `Tang.Website.UC.ArticleItems.GetLegacyDataTable(Int32 collectionId, Int32 maxRecord)`

Comment: When you restore user security does not always restore like you think.  I always delete and re-add Users under Security.  On the same box it would not be a problem but still worth a try.

Comment: @sixlettervariables. Source is as follows: 'public static string CutText(string rawText, int length){ string str = RemoveHtmlTags(StripHtml(rawText)); if (str.Length <= (length - 3)){ return str; } return (str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf(" ", (int) (length - 3))) + "...");}'.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure how to get that. Again, I apologize for my profanity, I am just an ex PHP developer :) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Blam, well, everything else works, there's a connection and you can add/edit/remove items, it's just not showing them on the front end. Could this still be the problem, do you think?

Comment: Doubt it is a security problem but still verify datareader (as it is separate from datawriter).

Comment: @Blam Tried it, doesn't seem to work. The thing is, as soon as I change the datbase from the webconfig file, everything works, I can add/remove/edit items and they are shown on the home page. So it's gotta be something between the website & the database and not code-related

Comment: @Phil - Stop saying `profanity` instead of `proficiency` it makes you look silly. If you have source code update the question itself do not use comments to post code.  Have you debugged the `CutText` to verify its not the problem?  Have you debugged `GetLegacyDataTable(Int32 collectionId, Int32 maxRecord)` to make sure that is not the problem.

Comment: Then I would debug with a simple select statement in a try catch block not bound to any UI and see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like length parameter comes with -1 value to CutText function. Is there an ORM tool you use? If you use Entity framework, you must set your connection string proper. Maybe your sql security properties doesn't let you to add. Sure look at your db when you add a news.

Comment: I have Visual Studio at hand. I was saying up in the comments, when you add/edit/remove articles, they seem to be saving properly and you have no problem accessing them from the back-end of the system, it's just the index page and the news list page that don't work. I'm not sure why this is and I'm not sure how to debug it?

Comment: @Phil You don't know how to go into debug mode in code behind?